# Reset password for regular user who is locked out

Tags: password, authentication, non-root-user, pam

I'm stuck in a situation where I'm logged in an Linux box from putty but on of my colleague, who was trying to login on same  machine from his machine blocked my user by entering wrong password for more than 3 times.
Now, I'm logged in but not able to reset the password as while trying Linux is asking for (LDAP) password after asking for UNIX password BUT, not accepting my user's LDAP password ( I'm just hoping it's same password which is used for outlook i.e. used with-in organization )

Is there any way to reset my password or we need to wait for the root user to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If your LDAP account has been locked in the directory, then I am afraid that only the directory administrator can unlock it.

Comment: I guess so .. will have to wait till admin will come to office :| But thanks for replying

Comment: @rahul yeah I mean, if it was a local account that was blocked, I guess you could recover it. But if it's locked somewhere else, there is not much you can do from your machine. At least, this is if I understood the situation correctly :)

Comment: @rahul Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Not yet, have sent the request to the admin server machine. hopefully will get sorted out soon.. About the situation, even i'm not aware of the problem entirely as i've been blocked by someone using my credential but me being already inside is a bit strange situation to be in. I was not able to reset the password nor the counter as told by 'Emmanuel' as pam_tally command could have require root/admin access. So i guess, it's mostly the permission issue .. But, Thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 0):

On the systems I know the "pam_tally" module manages the failure counts.

To check the pam_tally counter :

```
pam_tally --user username
```

To reset the counter :

```
pam_tally --user username --reset
```

That must be done under the *root* id.

Comment: Thanks for replying & your time Emmanual..
i'm not able to fetch the counter value, let's leave the case of reseting it ... it's replying 'command not found'. I guess i'm not able to access the command ( that's something as a laymen i can think of)